# Wiring residential internet router through existing smoke detector

Tags: wiring

My internet router is setup at one end of the house thus the other end gets bad coverage. I'd like to move it at the center of the house to provide better coverage.

The gear in question is located in the basement, everything is opened and wired at the moment.

Here is the center of the house, note the smoke detector:
[image]

Essentially, could I branch off the smoke detector to power the router (residential unit provided by my ISP)?

**Edit #1**

Per the comments below, I'll attempt to use the light fixture that is nearby:

[image]

I was only thinking of using the smoke detector as it was closer. Now I wonder if it's advisable if I branch off a 4th line from the light fixture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The 2011 version of the National Electrical Code made this very clear.

> ## National Electrical Code 2011
>
> ### Chapter 7 Special Conditions
>
> #### Article 760 Fire Alarm Systems
>
> **760.41 NPLFA Circuit Power Source Requirements**
>
> **(B) Branch Circuit.** The branch circuit supplying the fire
> alarm equipment(s) shall supply no other loads. The location
> of the branch circuit overcurrent protective device shall
> be permanently identified at the fire alarm control panel.
> This branch circuit shall not be supplied through ground-fault
> circuit interrupters or arc-fault circuit-interrupters.

The 2008 version was a bit vague about this, but the 2011 version leaves no doubt. You'll have to find a power source somewhere else.

---

While this code snippet *may* not be applicable to smoke detectors, it's still good advice to keep smoke detectors on their own circuit (in my opinion).

Comment: how about branching off a neighboring light instead?

Comment: See the reply from Schneider Electric (Square D) Here:
http://www.schneider-electric.us/sites/us/en/support/faq/faq_main.page?page=content&country=US&lang=en&locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US&id=FA128243&redirect=true

This is the interpretation of pretty much everyone I know.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey That may be the case; but in my opinion, it's bad form to have general use receptacles on the smoke detector circuit.

Comment: @tester101, opinions and code legalities can often be two different things.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Hopefully in an upcoming code version they will become one and the same.  There's no reason to put general use receptacles and lighting, on a smoke detector circuit.

Comment: Well I hope they do not. They are NOT one in the same. Personally I don't see a problem with this, especially in this case. It's no different than a lighting load shared with smokes which is very common in most areas. We can just agree to disagree.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Having fire safety devices on a general use circuit could be dangerous, and in my opinion should be avoided.  So I guess we will have to disagree on this.

Answer (score 4):

I'll have to disagree with Tester101 here.

A smoke detector, at least in my area, is NOT considered a "fire alarm", nor is it even implied in the name. It is extremely common to have smokes and CO detectors on a lighting circuit so they cannot be easily or conveniently turned off.

IMO powering a receptacle for a router is fine since the router is a negligible draw, and if it is off for any reason you will quickly want it back on.

See explanation in the reply here from Mike Holt:
http://ecmweb.com/qampa/code-qa-86

Comment: Yes. I think this is a matter of legislative code. however one nice thing about branching is that if the router power fails, you will know about it as soon as you try to check your stack-exchange account. I would be wary though, normally routers are quite specific about their input voltage, normally requiring roughly 9v DC. how do you plan to connect the router power unit (transformer) to the circuit?

Comment: A smoke alarm could easily be considered part of the "fire alarm system".

Comment: @hightower I was thinking of fashionning a plug and connecting the router using the original plug/adapter.

Comment: Also, if you provide a receptacle, there's no way to say for sure who is going to plug what in. Somebody could come along and plug in a power strip, to power their table saw and dust collection system.

Comment: Yes, it could be considered that Tester, but in my experience it is not considered that. Not by ANY inspector that I have encountered.
And what difference does it make what is plugged in? If it's too much the breaker will trip and the load adjusted, no?

Comment: One of the foremost authorities on the NEC agrees with my stance as well: http://ecmweb.com/qampa/code-qa-86
Quote: _"This is because a smoke alarm circuit isn't a fire alarm circuit as defined in NFPA 72, National Fire Alarm Code."_

Answer (score 0):

A individual smoke alarm is not governed by article 760 of the NEC, fire alarm equipment is for commercial/industrial use.  As long as the circuit is on an arc fault breaker, your fine to use this power for an outlet as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have to go with speedy and mark here.

Check this quote from ecmweb.com:

> As defined in NFPA 72, residential smoke alarm systems (including interconnecting wiring) are not powered by a fire alarm system. Therefore, Art. 760 does not cover them. 
>   http://m.ecmweb.com/code-basics/fire-alarm-system-facts

In Michigan, they are only required to be hard wired, interconnected, and powered from an AFCI since they are in the bedrooms.

It is probably a good idea to take your power from elsewhere but there is no code requirement for that.

Just my 2¢.

Happy Saturday!